# How do I positon three divs(one vertical and two horizontal) inside of another div?

Tags: css, html

I have three div layers inside of another larger one. Something like this:

[Image http://dev.kgstiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Stack.png](http://dev.kgstiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Stack.png)

Lets say the blue sections are the header and footer. What I currently have is the the green next to the top yellow div, but the bottom of the green div pushes the second yellow div down. I essentially have two divs next to each other then one div below both of them, but I want something more closely resembling the picture. What might I be missing that could put the green div next to both of the yellow ones?

I would post code exactly because there is a lot in each div, but I have something like:

```
<div class="container" >

<div id="greenDiv" style="float:right; padding-right:5%; padding-top:15px;">

</div>
<div id="topYellow" style="dsiplay:block;"> 

<-- Content -->
</div>
<div id="bottomYellow" style="dsiplay:block; float:left;"> 

<-- Content -->

</div>
```

What exactly do I need to do to keep the green div from pushing the bottom yellow one down? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using floats at all. If the green div has a fixed width, you could style them like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative; /* or anything besides static */
}

#greenDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px; 
}

#topYellow, #bottomYellow {
    margin-right: 100px; /* Plus more if you want a gap */
}
```

Essentially, this takes the green div out of the "flow" of the container. The yellow divs will simply be placed with a normal flow, and their margin prevents them from overlapping the green div. You could alternatively just float `#greenDiv` and not `#bottomYellow` instead of using absolute positioning. The benefit to this is that in case `#greenDiv` is taller than the two yellow, then doing a `clear: both` on the footer should ensure that `#greenDiv` and the footer don't overlap.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I had tried something similar, but didn't think to set the container's position to relative which set the green div outside of the container...Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both yellow elements and float that element, instead of the yellow ones, left, then float the green to the left.  Add in a clearfix before closing the overall container, and BOOM!  You have your yellow elements to the left, green to the right, and the container stretches to a height of whichever set is taller.

Answer (score 0):

set all div float:right;
first green div;
or :

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="letf_div" style="float:left">
     <div id="yelow1"></div>
     <div id="yelow2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right_div" style="float:left">
   <div id="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```